# IIS url rewrite rule not working with MVC controller actions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting

How to make IIS reverse proxy / url rewrite rules work with ASP.NET MVC actions? The rule (no matter how generic / specific) doesn't trigger if the pattern url is pointing to an MVC action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://forums.iis.net/t/1202822.aspx?IIS%20ARR%20with%20URLRewrite%20is%20not%20working%20ASP%20NET%20MVC%20application),

The solution is to ignore the URL explicitely in the ASP.NET MVC project like this:

```
routes.Ignore("MyRelativeURL/{*pathInfo}");
```

Comment: You can mark this as the correct answer (even if it is your own answer).